# Huge time of execution for getting data in MyBatis than the query run in sql developer

Tags: java, orm, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

A query takes 8 sec in sql dev but takes 50 s to get data in mybatis. Is there any way to optmise the process.

```xml
<select id="getData" resultType="java.util.HashMap" flushCache="false" useCache="true">
    SELECT distinct model as MODEL,category FROM TST
</select>
```

Call from java

```java
List<HashMap> resultdata = service.getData();
```

Comment: Does it take 8 seconds to fetch the *entire* result in SQL Developer? Or just the first 50 records that are displayed? Also: How many rows is the query expected to be returning?

Comment: yes and its returning 1800 rows.

Comment: That's not a lot. Have you run a profiler (e.g. Java Mission Control / Flight Recorder) to measure what's taking so long within MyBatis?

Comment: Well I am new to this so I haven't tried running a profiler and have no idea of how to do so.

Comment: Adding a fetchSize ="500" makes a good time for execution.